# Does $F$ have a local minimum at $0$?

Tags: calculus

I have tried to do this exercise. I'm always dubious about the use of the chain rule, is my solution correct?

Let $F \colon \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ with $F(x,y):=xye^x+ye^y-e^x+1$ and let $C$ be the zero set for $F$.

Now, let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^2$ such that, in (0,0), we have $\nabla f = \left( \begin{matrix} -2 \\ 2 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $H(f) = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$.

Is $(0,0)$ a local minimum for $f$ on $C$?

Thank you very much for the help!

PS I'm doing some exercises for a very important test which is about a lot of different stuff I might not even have seen in a course yet. So every kind comment, suggestion about somehow similar exercises or theorems/results/whatever that you think might help me out is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly F(0,0)=0 and $\partial y F = xe^x+e^y+ye^y$ and $\partial x F = ye^x+xye^x-e^x$. We have $\partial y F(0,0)=1$ and $\partial x F(0,0)=-1$.
Therefore we can apply Dini's theorem getting that, locally C is described by $(x,\phi(x))$ with $\phi(x)$ a derivable function with $\phi'(x)= -\frac{\partial x F(0,0)}{\partial y F(0,0)}=1$.

Now we have to see if (0,0) is a critical point for f in C:
$\partial f(x,\phi(x)) = \partial x f(x,\phi(x))\phi'(x) + \partial y f(x,\phi(x))\phi'(x)$ which in 0 becomes: $\partial f(0,\phi(0)) = -2*1+2*1=0$.

Since H(f) is positively defined we can conclude it is a minium point.